# How to convert a number to base 16 with math ( not using strings )?

Tags: python, math

Say i have

1009732533765201

and i want:

0x1009732533765201 which is

1155581383011619329

You can do this in programming languages with strings like this

int('1009732533765201',16)

but i want the pure math way. To convert 1009732533765201 to it's base16 of 1155581383011619329

I tried: int('1009732533765201',16)  but this uses a string, and is slow for large numbers, i'm looking for a math angle only.

Here is a math way i know how to do it:
0x1009732533765201 = 1155581383011619329

Here is a python way to do it:
 int('1009732533765201',16)

but i can only do the first math version manually. How can this be accomplished, converting 0x1009732533765201 without using a string to concatenating '0x' to '1009732533765201' and not using eval

Is there any way to take 1009732533765201, and convert it to the same ouput as 0x1009732533765201 to get its integer without using int('1009732533765201',16) my goal is to find a faster approach

ANSWERED BY PARTHIAN SHOT, here is the result of his approach which is exactly what i was looking for, a way to do this without int()

```
orig = 1009732533765201 
num = orig 
result = 0 
i = 0 
while num != 0: 
     result += (num % 10) * (16 ** i) 
     num //= 10 
     i += 1 

print(orig, num, result, "%x" % (result))
```

1009732533765201 0 1155581383011619329 1009732533765201

Comment: What do you meant by _"pure math way"_? What do you mean by _"not using strings"_? The hexadecimal representation of a number is a string by definition.

Comment: Under the hood integers in a computer tend to be represented using binary two's complement. Since hexadecimal (base 16) is an integer power of base 2, arguably any number you run across in a computer is already base 16.

Comment: However, your question is different, of course. You want to be able to mathematically interpret the decimal representation of a number as if it were hexadecimal. That's simple enough. I'll write a thing.

Comment: Can you tell us why `int('1009732533765201',16)` isn't sufficient? Your own code to compute it is extremely unlikely to be faster than Python's.

Comment: Python just know how to deal with ```0x``` notation (and other bases) out of box. Just go ahead and assign a variable like ```i = 0x16```. There is no need to use strings for that.

Answer (score 1):

As I said in my comment, Python knows, out of box, how to deal with base 16 numbers. Just go ahead and assign the base 16 value to a variable.

Here is an example:

```
Python 3.7.4 (default, Aug 12 2019, 14:45:07) 
[GCC 9.1.1 20190605 (Red Hat 9.1.1-2)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> i=0x16
>>> i
22
>>> i=0xAA
>>> i
170
>>>
```

And as I said, that works for other bases, like base 2:

```
>>> i=0b1010
>>> i
10
>>>
```

And base 8:

```
>>> i=0o12
>>> i
10
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

The idea here is that we're looking at each digit of the original decimal number one at a time, from right to left, and multiplying it by `16 ** i` instead of `10 ** i`, then adding it to the new number.

The result is the equivalent of interpreting the original decimal representation of the number as if it were hexadecimal.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

orig = 34029235
num = orig
result = 0
i = 0
while num != 0:
    result += (num % 10) * (16 ** i)
    num //= 10
    i += 1

print(orig, num, result, "%x" % (result))
```

And running that code gets us...

```
bash$ ./main.py 
(34029235, 0, 872583733, '34029235')
bash$
```

Comment: This is the answer i wanted!!! i wanted to take int, like 1009, and get 0x1009 for the answer of 4105, and your code worked without a string!

Comment: @oppressionslayer your question was not clear at all.  I would not have known this is what you wanted if you hadn't highlighted this answer.

Comment: @MarkRansom I'll edit my message here soon to make the question clearer in the hopes that it helps someone in the future. This is actually useful, so i'll definitely edit it.

Comment: I'd argue that the OP was pretty clear in what they wanted. The phrasing wasn't perfect, but the intent was abundantly clear. Which is why I had no trouble figuring out the question and coming up with this answer.